# Setting a base url for urls generated by Spring

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

We've got a restful api running using spring which generates HATEOAS links. When I run the service locally, they are generated fine, but on our server, which hosts tomcat behind apache which proxies the app to /api/ (locally it's just run on /), the urls are still generated like the app is run on /.

Is there any way to tell spring to use a base url when generating these?

Comment: The easiest is to just change your application's context path to match the public API path. A second alternative is to use something like `mod_substitute` to regex all of the responses.

Comment: I tried setting server.contextPath="/api/", but that just made the production server serve everyhing on /api/api/...

Comment: If your context path is `/api/`, then apache should proxy to `/api/`, not to `/` on tomcat.

Comment: I found the solution, will post below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured out my problem. Spring wasn't at fault. When building links, spring uses the X-Forwarded-Host, X-Forwarded-Ssl, etc. and, since 4.1.3, X-Forwarded-Prefix to correctly build urls that will be forwarded by a proxy. This last one however, is not automatically set by apache when proxying, so installing mod_headers and adding `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "api"`to my LocationMatch  directive solved everything.

Comment: Excellent, saved me on this one big time - ty.

Comment: I needed to add a leading slash, e.g. `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/api"`